# R Shiny - Nesting observers

Tags: r, shiny

In the app below, the user chooses a letter which is appended to a vector of their choice as long as the selector vector does not already contain that letter. The user first chooses a letter via a selectInput (id = `letters`) and then chooses which vector to add this letter to via another `selectInput`, (id = `vec`) before clicking `Apply`.

When the user clicks `Apply`, an observeEvent checks if the selected letter already exists in the selected vector and stores the result of the check inside `rv$valid`. `rv$valid` is `FALSE` if the letter is a duplicate and `TRUE` if the letter is **not** a duplicate. If `rv$valid == FALSE` (i.e. the letter is a duplicate), then the user is alerted and asked to either choose a different letter or a different vector.

I would like to run this check each time the user changes either `input$letter` or `input$vec` **subsequent** to clicking `Apply` and toggle the alert based on the value of that check. How can I do this? I have tried creating an observer inside the observeEvent that listens to the `Apply` button but it doesn't work as expected. [If the user changes their selection for `input$vec` and clicks `Apply` again, the message is displayed even if the letter is not a duplicate.](https://gfycat.com/onlyfantasticblacknorwegianelkhound)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    selectInput('letter', 'Step1: Choose a letter.', letters),
    selectInput('vec', 'Step 2: Which vector would you like to append this letter to?', c('vec1', 'vec2', 'vec3')),
    actionButton('apply', 'Apply'),
    hidden(tags$p(id = 'alert', style = 'color:red;', 'Selected vector already contains this letter. Choose a different vector or letter.')),
    lapply(c('vec1', 'vec2', 'vec3'), verbatimTextOutput)
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {

    rv <- reactiveValues(vec1 = NULL, vec2 = NULL, vec3 = NULL, valid = FALSE)


    observeEvent(input$apply, {

      rv$valid = !input$letter %in% rv[[input$vec]]

      if(!rv$valid) {

        observe({

          rv$valid = !input$letter %in% rv[[input$vec]]

          toggle(id = 'alert', condition = !rv$valid)

        }) 

      } 


    }, ignoreInit = T)

    observeEvent(input$apply, {

      req(rv$valid)

      rv[[input$vec]] = c(rv[[input$vec]], input$letter)
    })

    lapply(c('vec1', 'vec2', 'vec3'), function(x, output, rv) {output[[x]] <- renderPrint(rv[[x]])}, output = output, rv = rv)

  }
)
```

Edit: Using `suspended = T` for the `observe()` does the trick but I'm still not sure about nesting observers in this way and would like to know if someone knew of a better solution. Here is the updated code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    selectInput('letter', 'Step1: Choose a letter.', letters),
    selectInput('vec', 'Step 2: Which vector would you like to append this letter to?', c('vec1', 'vec2', 'vec3')),
    actionButton('apply', 'Apply'),
    hidden(tags$p(id = 'alert', style = 'color:red;', 'Selected vector already contains this letter. Choose a different vector or letter.')),
    lapply(c('vec1', 'vec2', 'vec3'), verbatimTextOutput)
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {

    rv <- reactiveValues(vec1 = NULL, vec2 = NULL, vec3 = NULL, valid = FALSE)

    obs <- observe({

      rv$valid = !input$letter %in% rv[[input$vec]]

      toggle(id = 'alert', condition = !rv$valid)

    })

    observeEvent(input$apply, {

      rv$valid = !input$letter %in% rv[[input$vec]]

      if(!rv$valid) 
        obs$resume()
      else 
        obs$suspend()

    }, ignoreInit = T)

    observeEvent(input$apply, {

      req(rv$valid)

      rv[[input$vec]] = c(rv[[input$vec]], input$letter)
    })

    lapply(c('vec1', 'vec2', 'vec3'), function(x, output, rv) {output[[x]] <- renderPrint(rv[[x]])}, output = output, rv = rv)

  }
)
```

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

A single `observeEvent` is sufficient. Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    selectInput('letter', 'Step1: Choose a letter.', letters),
    selectInput('vec', 'Step 2: Which vector would you like to append this letter to?', c('vec1', 'vec2', 'vec3')),
    actionButton('apply', 'Apply'),
    p(hidden(tags$p(id = 'alert', style = 'color:red;', 'Selected vector already contains this letter. Choose a different vector or letter.'))),
    lapply(c('vec1', 'vec2', 'vec3'), verbatimTextOutput)
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {

    rv <- reactiveValues(vec1 = NULL, vec2 = NULL, vec3 = NULL, valid = FALSE)

    observeEvent(input$apply, {
      rv$valid = !input$letter %in% rv[[input$vec]]
      toggle(id = 'alert', condition = !rv$valid)
      req(rv$valid)
      rv[[input$vec]] = c(rv[[input$vec]], input$letter)
    })

    lapply(c('vec1', 'vec2', 'vec3'), function(x, output, rv) {output[[x]] <- renderPrint(rv[[x]])}, output = output, rv = rv)

  }
)
```